# Save latest string values in react state array

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a form in react containing multiple text boxes. I am trying to fetch the values of all text boxes on click of a button. For that I am using an array of states. Here´s my state which is an array of objects:

```
const [myState, setMyState] = useState([{
   stringValue: {
      name: "",
      value: ""
   },
       
}])
```

And here´s my text field:

```
<TextField 
  onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
      setMyState([...myState, {
        stringValue: {
          name: displayName,
          value: e.target.Value
        }
      },])}
/>
```

On button click I want to get the values of all textboxes but since I am using a state array, my `myState` array looks something like this :

```
h
he
hel
hell
hello
```

If I don´t use state array, I end up overwriting the state. How can I get I save the full string "hello" to `myState` instead of all the individual characters?

Comment: if you can try discarding the old value , when setting state of the new value.

Comment: @Yousaf You shouldn´t have deleted the answer you posted yesterday. It was helpful.

Comment: Actually, i am adding the demo posted in the comment in the answer. Let me edit the answer, then i will un-delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an array to save and retrieve the values of all the input fields in the form.

Instead of using an array, use a object literal that will hold the values of all the input fields in the form. Your state could have the following structure

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
   input1: '',
   input2: '',
   input3: ''
});
```

And make each input field a [`controlled component`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), meaning its value will be driven by the state of the component.

This way you can access the values of all the fields and update the value of the input fields using only a single `onChange` event handler.

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
   const { name, value } = event.target;
   setData({ ...data, [name]: value });
};
```

Following code snippet shows an example:

```js
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState({
    input1: "",
    input2: "",
    input3: ""
  });

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setData({ ...data, [name]: value });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="input1"
        value={data.input1}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        name="input2"
        value={data.input2}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        name="input3"
        value={data.input3}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <br />
      {JSON.stringify(data)}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
input { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

#### Edit:

If you want to create input fields dynamically, then you can create the input fields dynamically using the the array or an object that represents the different input fields in the `form`.

Following code snippet shows an example:

```js
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState({
    input1: { type: "text", value: "", name: "input1" },
    input2: { type: "text", value: "", name: "input2" },
    input3: { type: "text", value: "", name: "input3" }
  });

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setData({ ...data, [name]: { ...data[name], value } });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(data).map((k) => {
        const { type, value, name } = data[k];
        return (
          <input
            key={k}
            type={type}
            value={value}
            name={name}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        );
      })}
      <br />
      {/* just for demo */}
      {Object.keys(data).map((k) =>
        JSON.stringify({ name: data[k].name, value: data[k].value })
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
input { display: block; margin: 8px 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, @Yousaf. I understand what you mean. But what if the number of text boxes is not fixed and is to be created dynamically? How would I change the value argument as shown here: `value={data.input2}`

Comment: Demo linked in the comment has been included in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

add value in TextField

```
<TextField
value={state.value}
```